# overlay image on an image in android? possible?

Tags: android, overlay

I have a CustomIcon class that displays a png using ImageView.  I m going to want to be able to place another image view overtop of it on the fly and be able to hide/show the overlay.  Can someone point me to a good tutorial to get me rolling?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would be well served by a RelativeLayout.  This layout allows you (among other things) to place Views on top of each other.

You can see some ["official" docs](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=android%20relativelayout%20tutorial&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html&ei=bhxaT7GxGoGEtgeL2Z2FDA&usg=AFQjCNFv2vnpJ80brDhuqU9FPY9_kgFvOg), and also a [tutorial from Learn Android](http://www.learn-android.com/2010/01/05/android-layout-tutorial/5/).

Comment: Thanks, don't suppose you know a tutorial that uses java for this instead of xml layout

Comment: Well, a quick Google for "android relativelayout java example" yields this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327144/setting-up-relativelayout-in-java-code