# Populate Buttons in Activity class

Tags: android, button

I want to populate the alphabet buttons in the activity class like this...

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
private void populateButtons() {
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout01);
        for (char buttonChar = 'A'; buttonChar <= 'Z'; buttonChar++) {
            String buttonText = String.valueOf(buttonChar);
            Button alphabetButton = new Button(this);
            alphabetButton.setText(buttonText);
            layout.addView(alphabetButton);
        }
        
    }
```

It results to this:

[image]

I can manually put all the alphabet buttons as follows but I think that coding it in the Activity class is better:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/violet"
        android:text="A"
        android:textColor="@color/main"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:onClick="methodHere" />
```

So how can i convert the above xml code using a java code in Activity class.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Use ``GridView`` not ``RelativeLayout``

Comment: how can i insert the button inside the grid?

Comment: You can use Gridview or TableLayout also  for this .

Comment: you have to use the Adapter to insert the buttons inside the Grid.

Comment: @newbie try to apply my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
private void populateButtons() {

        ArrayAdapter<String> chars = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        GridView layout = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        for (char buttonChar = 'A'; buttonChar <= 'Z'; buttonChar++) {
            String buttonText = String.valueOf(buttonChar);
            chars.add(buttonText);
        }
        layout.setAdapter(chars);
    }
```

If you really want to insert buttons, create a class which extends `Adapter`,

`ArrayAdapter` is enough.

```
public class AlphabetButtonAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{

        private List<String> objects;
        public AlphabetButtonAdapter(Context context,
                int textViewResourceId,
                List<String> objects)
        {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            this.objects = objects;

        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            Button b = new Button(getContext());
            b.setText(objects.get(position));
            return b;
        }

        public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener listener)
        {
             this.listener = listener;
        }

}
```

Populating using customized adapter

```
private void populateButtons() {


            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();            
            GridView layout = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
            for (char buttonChar = 'A'; buttonChar <= 'Z'; buttonChar++) {
                String buttonText = String.valueOf(buttonChar);
                list.add(buttonText);
            }

            AlphabetButtonAdapter chars = new AlphabetButtonAdapter(context, 0, list);
            layout.setAdapter(chars);

        }
```

UPDATE 1: Binding `onClick()` in button

You can pass the `OnClickListener` in `AlphabetButtonAdapter` just add a setter method

```
public class MyActivity OnClickListener
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
             Button b = (Button) v;
             // Your definition...

    }
}

private void populateButtons() {


                ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();            
                GridView layout = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
                for (char buttonChar = 'A'; buttonChar <= 'Z'; buttonChar++) {
                    String buttonText = String.valueOf(buttonChar);
                    list.add(buttonText);
                }

                AlphabetButtonAdapter chars = new AlphabetButtonAdapter(context, 0, list);
                chars.setOnClickListener(listener);
                layout.setAdapter(chars);

}
```

Comment: why is  AlphabetButtonAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) !=  public Asa(Context context,
                int resource,
                int textViewResourceId,
                List<String> objects)
        { ?

Comment: keyboard's fault, I'm sorry :)

Comment: what parameter should i put in resource, textViewResourceId, objects?

Comment: View IDs like ``android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1``, that will not be used because I created a button object and return it from ``getView()``

Comment: should i initialize it like this?   AlphabetButtonAdapter chars = new AlphabetButtonAdapter(this, 0, 0, null);

Comment: 1 parameter is still missing AlphabetButtonAdapter(context, 0, list)

Comment: error on this.. return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

Comment: change it to ``return b``;

Comment: oks.. its now working.. but how can i bind it to the onclick method?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot ID's. Set ID's for the Buttons as discussed here.

[Setting up RelativeLayout in java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327144/setting-up-relativelayout-in-java-code)

That will make code to:

```
private void populateButtons(){

  RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout01); 

  for (char buttonChar = 'A'; buttonChar <= 'Z'; buttonChar++){

        String buttonText = String.valueOf(buttonChar);
        Button alphabetButton = new Button(this);
        alphabetButton.setId('A');// This is just an unique integer.
        alphabetButton.setText(buttonText);
        layout.addView(alphabetButton);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use LinearLayout with Horizontal orientation and a fixed Width and Weight params, instead of RelativeLayout cited above. Try altering your activity layout and also your code like bellow:

private void populateButtons() {

```
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout01);

    for (char buttonChar = 'A'; buttonChar <= 'Z'; buttonChar++) {
        String buttonText = String.valueOf(buttonChar);
        Button alphabetButton = new Button(this);
        alphabetButton.setText(buttonText);
        layout.addView(alphabetButton);
    }

}
```